# Make All Observables subscribeon and observeon something

Tags: android, retrofit, rx-java, rx-android

i'm implementing http requests using retrofit and rxjava in my android app.
and i have this block code repeatedly:

```
apiService.getFromServer()
 .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
 .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
 ...
```

is there a way not to repeat this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can use the `compose` operator with `Transformer` object that will transform input observable to `Observable` that subscribes on io, observer on mainThread (or any other transformation you like of course)

```
<T> Transformer<T, T> applySchedulers() {  
return new Transformer<T, T>() {
    @Override
    public Observable<T> call(Observable<T> observable) {
        return observable.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread());
    }
    };
}
```

and your code:

```
apiService.getFromServer()    
   .compose(applySchedulers())
   ...
```

you can read [Dan Lew's great post](http://blog.danlew.net/2015/03/02/dont-break-the-chain/) regarding that.